# Recursive Palindrom does not returning neither true nor false only undefined

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I've tried to write a recursive palindrom however, eventhough I reach at the end the true branch at the last iteration the return value is still undefined.

So if you type in the console my function with a palindrom.
rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom("radar");

It will iterate through it perfectly but the return value,  will be undefined.
Could you please point out the error in my code below ?
Thanks

```
function rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str, strLength = str.length) {
// debug eleje
console.log(strLength);
if (strLength > 1) {
console.log(str[str.length - strLength] + "  " +str[strLength-1] );
}
if(strLength == 1){
console.log(str[str.length-1]+ "   " +str[strLength-1]);
}
//debug vége
  if(typeof str == "string" || typeof str == "number"){
    if(typeof str == "number"){
       str = str.toString();
    }
  
    
    if(strLength > 1){
      if(str[str.length - strLength] == str[strLength-1]){
        //console.log(strLength);
        strLength--;
        
        rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str,strLength);
        }

    }
    else if(strLength == 1){
      if(str[str.length-1] == str[strLength-1]){
       console.log(strLength+"true");
        return true;
      }
      else{
        console.log(strLength+"false");
        return false;
        }    
        

      }

    }

    else {
      return false;

    }   
     
  }
```

Comment: try returning the recursive call  `return rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str,strLength);` so that the recursive execution is done properly.

Comment: `function rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str, strLength = str.length)`: `str.length` doesn't work on numbers - you haven't converted them to a string yet.

Comment: `strLength--; return rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str,strLength);`: you may be clipping the end, but not the beginning.

Comment: Look at my code and compare logic and see where the differences are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return the result of your recursive call.

```js
function rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str, strLength = str.length) {
// debug eleje
console.log(strLength);
if (strLength > 1) {
console.log(str[str.length - strLength] + "  " +str[strLength-1] );
}
if(strLength == 1){
console.log(str[str.length-1]+ "   " +str[strLength-1]);
}
//debug vége
  if(typeof str == "string" || typeof str == "number"){
    if(typeof str == "number"){
       str = str.toString();
    }
  
    
    if(strLength > 1){
      if(str[str.length - strLength] == str[strLength-1]){
        //console.log(strLength);
        strLength--;
        
        return rekurzivSzigoruPalindrom(str,strLength);
        }

    }
    else if(strLength == 1){
      if(str[str.length-1] == str[strLength-1]){
       console.log(strLength+"true");
        return true;
      }
      else{
        console.log(strLength+"false");
        return false;
        }    
        

      }

    }

    else {
      return false;

    }   
     
  }
```

Comment: You've use a snippet - could you add some test strings/numbers to show that your code is working?

Comment: the return statement

Comment: Oh!  in `if(strLength > 1)`!  Sorry - missed that (and I looked!  Time for new glasses...).

Comment: no worries! I didn't run the code to check if it works, OP is trying to figure this out but I figured pointing out where the return statement was missing in their recursion would answer their question

Comment: It's hard to follow someone else's code/logic sometimes (I'm referring to the question).
So, I just wrote a solution for the intent (plus some digging and commenting about possible problems).
Your thoughts about my solution?

Comment: You are the most awsome person I've ever met. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Recursive:

```js
function recPal(str) {
  str=""+str; // for numbers
  if(str.length<2) return true;
  if(str[0]!=str[str.length-1]) return false;
  return recPal(str.slice(1,-1));
};

var strs=[101, 75, "", "x", "xy", "99", "abba", "log", "racecar", "razor", "radar"];

strs.forEach(
  word=>
    console.log(
      "'"+word+"'"+
      (recPal(word)?" IS ":" is NOT ")+
      "a palindrome"
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow clean and simple. Thank you :) I've learned a lot from it.

Comment: Glad to help + You are welcome!
Can you select my answer + up-vote when you have 15 reputation points?

Comment: I've upvoted it however I've accepted  Ethan Lipkind's answer because he corrected my original code and Stack overflow does not allow me to accept both answer :(